# FastCGI not compatible with Carp fatalsToBrowser?

Tags: perl, fastcgi

I am developing a Perl script using *FastCGI* (using `CGI::Fast` and `CGI::Carp 'fatalsToBrowser')`.
When my script has compile errors, it causes the browser to hang. It seems that `fatalsToBrowser` is not working the way it does with normal CGI (just send the compile errors to the browser).  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the CGI.pm maintainer. I would recommend avoiding using 'fatalsToBrowser' in this case. Some Perl frameworks over features which do the same thing. For example, with CGI::Application there is [CGI::Application::Plugin::DebugScreen](http://search.cpan.org/~nekokak/CGI-Application-Plugin-DebugScreen-1.00/). Other frameworks have something similar.

In other cases, the popular 'Carp' and 'CGI::Carp' modules can conflict if they both end up imported in the same name space, because they both provide functions with the same names, like 'carp' and 'croak'. I recommend using Carp and avoiding CGI::Carp.

Answer (score 3):

I can not offer you a workaround but only an explanation, FastCGI works completely differently. When a CGI application is executed standard descriptors and environ is provided before execution, in a FastCGI application the server (application) must first accept a connection from the client (usually webserver) and exchange a few messages/records before a request is accepted and response can be sent. CGI::Carp does it's magic during perl's compile phase and assumes that standard descriptors is available when the syntax error occurs (compile phase) and that is to early for CGI::Fast.pm.

I'm one of the maintainers of FCGI.pm(and libfcgi) so I'll work with the CGI maintainers to get this resolved.

Comment: Thanks... can you also look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013354/cgisession-sharing-sessions-between-clients